# How can i change Attribute FIlter as a Drop Down Instead of list

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, filter, dropdown-attribute

I need to change my attribute selection as a drop down instead list. User can manually click what they are need to be applied  filter of products.

Attribute List :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The block you are asking to change is a price filter block, of type `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price`.

It extends the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract` and the phtml template is assigned in the `__construct()` method to `catalog/layer/filter.phtml`.

If you want to customize the price filter you have different options:

- perform a block rewrite, use your own block which extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price` and assign your own template in the `__construct()` method; I discourage this approach;
- add a layout rule which changes the template of the price filter block; this is the approach I prefer so I explain it below.

To change the template we need to **reference the price filter block by its name in layout**; the problem is that the price filter block has a dynamic layout name.

It has the fixed alias `price_filter` but it can only be used to retrieve a child from a parent block; the parent block has `catalog.leftnav` fixed name in layout so with the following snippet placed at the bottom of the `index.php` we'll retrieve the price filter name in layout (from a layered category page):

```
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$leftNav = $layout->getBlock('catalog.leftnav');
if ($leftNav) {
    $priceFilter = $leftNav->getChild('price_filter');
    if ($priceFilter) {
        var_dump($priceFilter->getNameInLayout());
    }
}
```

**Warning:** this means *"touching the core"* so restore the original `index.php` as soon as you have retrieved the price filter block name.

In my case the price filter block name is `catalog.leftnav.child2` so I can use this name to add a layout rule as follows:

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="catalog.leftnav.child2">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>[custom_template_path]</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

To build your custom template, start from `catalog/layer/filter.phtml`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the simplest way I didn't think to is that of changing the `catalog/layer/filter.phtml` file of your custom template